# Android directing to new page based on user role saved in xampp

Tags: java, php, android, xampp

Ive followed a tutorial and right now ive got a login coding which can check if user exist and check the user role (admin or user).

Ive read that to get to new page we need to use Intent but how do i get the userrole of it to pass into android? where admin will be directed to page A and user to page B.

Tqvm in advanced.

1.BackgroundWorker.java

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://ipaddress/foldername/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

2.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void OnLogin(View view){
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";


    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
}

}
```

3.login.php

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from employee_data where username like '$user_name'  and      password like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while ($data =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

                $userrole = $data['role'];  

                if ($userrole == "admin"){


                    echo "login admin successful";

                }

                else if ($userrole == "user")
                {

                    echo "login user successful";
                }

            }

        }
else{
echo "login unsuccessful";
}



?>
```

p.s im very much new to android so any explanation is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by echoing the role, if the login is successful, in your PHP script:

```
echo $user['role'];
```

and only echo "login failed" or simply "failed". Then you could parse the response from your `onPostExecute()` method like so:

```
switch (result) {
    case "failed":
        // Login failed.
        break;
    case "user": // Login successful, result (role) is "user"
        break;
    case "admin": // Login successful, result (role) is "admin"
        break;
}
```

If you want to pass this role back to your activity, you could implement a listener interface on your `AsyncTask` that will be invoked when the `onPostExecute()` method is called. For example:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    ... // Member properties.
    // Define the listener interface.
    public interface OnTaskFinishedListener {
        void onTaskFinished(String result);
    }

    // Member property to reference listener.
    private OnTaskFinishedListener mOnTaskFinishedListener;

    // Setter for listener.
    public void setOnTaskFinishedListener(OnTaskFinishedListener listener) {
        mOnTaskFinishedListener = listener;
    }

    // Invoke the listener in the onPostExecute() method.
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Only call it if it's set.
        if (mOnTaskFinishedListener != null) 
            mOnTaskFinishedListener.onTaskFinished(result);
    }
}
```

Then in your activity, in `OnLogin()`:

```
public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";


    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);

    // Set your listener here.
    backgroundWorker.setOnTaskFinishedListener(new BackgroundWorker.OnTaskFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskFinished(String result) {
            // Now you have the result of your login here.
            // Result should be "admin", "user", or "failed"
            // You can now create an intent and open the page 
            // to your next activity.
            switch (result) {
                case "admin":
                    // Create your intent.
                    Intent adminIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminPageActivity.class);

                    // Start the admin page activity.
                    startActivity(adminIntent);
                    break;
                case "user":
                    // Create your intent.
                    Intent userIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPageActivity.class);

                    // Start the user page activity.
                    startActivity(userIntent);
                    break;
                default:
                    // Login failed.
            }
        }
    });

    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
}
```

The listener stuff can be tricky to grasp at first, but once you do, it's extremely powerful.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This sure did helps a lot. im gonna learn the listener stuff first and try to understand your explanation. tqvm again.

Comment: No problem. Multithreading and listener interfaces go hand in hand. It's a very efficient way to "sync" (and I use that term loosely) back up with your UI thread once the background task is finished. Also, just a friendly heads up, if you feel this question has helped you with your problem, consider marking it as correct. Thanks and have a good one.

Comment: hi again. tqvm for your help yesterday. i just posted a new question which i hope that you could spend some time on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170144/illegalstateexception-thrown-for-my-app-in-android?noredirect=1#comment58058973_35170144.