# IllegalStateException thrown for my app in Android

Tags: java, php, android, xampp

So my 1st part login is working. There is no problem with it. Now when I try to use the same application for registration it just stopped working. I'm lost here and I'm new in android development, so I don't really understand the error given.

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    }

    public void OnLogin(View view){
        String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);

        backgroundWorker.setOnTaskFinishedListener(new BackgroundWorker.OnTaskFinishedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTaskFinished(String result) {
                // Now you have the result of your login here.
                // Result should be "admin", "user", or "failed"
                // You can now create an intent and open the page
                // to your next activity.
                switch (result) {
                    case "admin":
                        // Create your intent.
                        Intent adminIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminPageActivity.class);
                        // Start the admin page activity.
                        startActivity(adminIntent);
                        break;

                    case "user":
                        // Create your intent.
                        Intent userIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPageActivity.class);
                        // Start the user page activity.
                        startActivity(userIntent);
                        break;

                    default:
                        // Login failed.
                        Intent failIntent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(failIntent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    }

    public void openRegistration(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Registration.class));
    }
}
```

**Registration.java**

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText NameEt, RoleEt, UsernameEt, PasswordEt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        NameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        RoleEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRole);
    }

    public void OnRegister(View view) {
        String str_name = NameEt.getText().toString();
        String str_username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
        String str_password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
        String str_role = RoleEt.getText().toString();
        String type = "register";

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_name, str_username, str_password, str_role);
    }

}
```

**BackgroundWorker.java**

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://ipaddress/folder/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://ipaddress/folder/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8") +"&" + URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(type.equals("register")) {
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String username = params[2];
                String password = params[3];
                String role = params[4];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("role","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(role,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public interface OnTaskFinishedListener {
        void onTaskFinished(String result);
    }

    // Member property to reference listener.
    private OnTaskFinishedListener mOnTaskFinishedListener;

    // Setter for listener.
    public void setOnTaskFinishedListener(OnTaskFinishedListener listener) {
        mOnTaskFinishedListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();

        switch (result) {
            case "failed":
                // Login failed.
                break;
            case "user": // Login successful, result (role) is "user"
                result = "user";
                break;
            case "admin": // Login successful, result (role) is "admin"
                result = "admin";
                break;
        }

        if (mOnTaskFinishedListener != null) {
            mOnTaskFinishedListener.onTaskFinished(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

I have just added another `if else` for registration on `backgroundworker.java`.

**register.php**

```
<?php 

require "conn.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$role = $_POST["role"];


$mysql_qry = "insert into  employee_data (name, username, password, role)  values ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$role')";

if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
    echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "fail".$mysql_qry."<br>".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

I'm stuck here please help.

**error log**

```
Process: com.example.user.mysqldemo, PID: 1325
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.user.mysqldemo.Registration.OnRegister(Registration.java:28)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

6.Activity_registration.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Role"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etRole"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bRegister"
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="OnRegister"/>
```

Comment: Please log the error that you are getting

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: just edited the error. not sure how to put it in format for stackoverflow. sorry about that

Comment: It's fine. So which line is 28 and which variable is null? Debugger will show it

Comment: in registration.java line 28 is String str_username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen for the variable is null, are you pointing out for this "java.lang.NullPointerException" because im not sure how to find the variable as it did not state the line number which can direct me to it.

Comment: It says line 28. Debugger can catch the exception when it happens, maybe. Java and Android are a bit bad at that by default though. Breakpoint on line 28 should help

Comment: Please post `activity_registration.xml`

Comment: @MustansarSaeed i just add activity_registration.xml

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `android:onClick` attribute then you have to make the `widget` `clickable` as well. Update the xml to

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bRegister"
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="OnRegister"/>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
this line `UsernameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);` is the culprit as `register_activity xml` does not contain id `etUserName`. It is pointing to some other xml instead this xml contains this id `etUsername`

Comment: awww.. you got me really excited there for a moment. but unfortunately. it still stop working.. got me sad again.. lol. still tq though.

Comment: did you see the updated answer? `etUserName` should be `etUsername` as activity registration xml does not contain `etUserName`

Comment: ooooo... i didnt realize you updated your answer.. i was doing the xml file before.. lol.. now everything is working. tqvm for helping.. now i feel stupid for messing up the upper and lowercase.. demmit.. tq again..